# mongoimport is not showing the collection after import has run successfully

Tags: mongodb, filesize, csv, mongoimport

I am using following command to import a large, approx. 50Gb, file in mongo. I am using the following command:

```
./mongoimport --host localhost --db <dbname> --collection part1 --type tsv --file part1_Final.tsv --headerline --upsert
```

After hours, it says successfully imported the rows, but when I go and check in my db it doesn't show up. However, when I use the same command with a file of much smaller size it works fine.

Kindly let me know if someone faced the similar issue and got it to work.

Comment: did you solve this? out of curiosity, do you have any indexes on your collection?

Comment: No. I did not have index on the collection.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that this was also asked on Google Groups, and has been addressed there.
http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/715806c48d03db8d/f84ed96da990c9fb

The fact that the operation is taking a while coupled with the fact that the output says that the rows were successfully imported indicates that the collection was imported somewhere.

You can view all of your database names by typing `show dbs` into your JS shell.  You can switch between databases by typing `use <database name>`, and you can view the collections in each database by typing `show collections`.  Perhaps a type-o caused the collection to be imported into a database other than you expected?

As Eliot stated on the Google Groups page, the server log might indicate where the collection was imported to.

Hopefully this will help you to find your collection!

Comment: That was indeed my own issues. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some change in the mongo import command.

get the *connection string* from the "connect with mongo shell" under the **connect button** in the cluster.

connection string typically ends with db name:

```
mongodb+srv://cluster0.hfsei.mongodb.net/<DB Name>
```

the command that works for me is as follows:

```
mongoimport "mongodb+srv://cluster0.hfsei.mongodb.net/<DB Name>" --username <db username> --password <password> --type csv --collection=<collection_name> --file=<file csv> --headerline
```