# mongoimport leaves collection empty for a while

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I do

```
mongoimport --host myhost --port myport --db mydb --collection mycollection --fields field_one,field_two --type csv --file myfile.csv
```

And this returns without error (even if I add `--stopOnError` it returns with exist status 0 and no errors).

Then if I do

```
mongo myhost:myport/mydb --eval "db.mycollection.find()"
```

and it returns

```
DBQuery: mydb.mycollection -> undefined
```

However, when I log into the mongo console I see that the data is there.

```
mongo myhost:myport/mydb
> db.mycollection.find()
// data here
```

Any suggestions? I'm using mongo 2.2.

I saw the similar question [mongoimport is not showing the collection after import has run successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177242/mongoimport-is-not-showing-the-collection-after-import-has-run-successfully), but checking the server logs I'm not seeing anything amiss.

Comment: If you change ".find()" to ".findOne" does it work? This is likely that find() returns a cursor rather than a result set. The shell provides a printout of results when run from within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ".find()" call returns a cursor. The shell adds value in that it will iterate over the cursor and print the first X results and allow for iteration.

To run your query using --eval try:

```
mongo myhost:myport/mydb --eval  "db.mycollection.find().forEach(printjson)"
```